# Border top and bottom for the same Div

Tags: html, css

How to add Border- bottom and border-top to the same Div?!

For me it works with whether bottom border or top border, but not with both:

```
.cat-name {

  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC

}
```

- doesn't work :(

But

```
.cat-name {

      border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC

    }
```

- work; and also

  .cat-name {

  ```
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC

  }
  ```
- work;
- But how to make both to work?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding semicolons `;` after each rule:

```
.cat-name {

  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

}
```